# Prove that a set A is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have been trying to solve this problem, I have a set $A=\{(x,y):a\le x\le b, 0\le y\le f(x)\}$ and I need to show that this set is measurable. $f$ is a positive continuous function.

UPDATE: I am approaching the problem by using the fact that A must be either other or closed so it means that $A$ is measurable, the definition I have is:
$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists A_\epsilon \in R $ such that: $\lambda ^*(A\triangle A_\epsilon) <\epsilon$, how do I take this $A_\epsilon$ to continue the proof?

I have already proved that its measure is the integral given by $\int_a^bf(x)dx$, I feel that I skipped one step by doing this, however, I don't have ideas about how to prove that A is indeed measurable. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: what is $f$ ? measurable positive function ?

Comment: Positive continuous function

Comment: @Adelinne Welcome! Please add context and show  your attempt.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have such attempt, I am just asking for hints that can guide me in this problem.

Comment: Here is how to approach the problem. (1) Find the definition of a measurable set you are using. (2) Inspect the course material or book you are reading for any criteria or theorems that might be useful. (3) Try to apply the tools you identified at step 2 to your particular problem. Update the question if you run into difficulties.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, then $A$ is closed, and thus obviously a Borel set, and thus Lebesgue-measurable.

Comment: Thank you, how should I prove that it is closed?, I am sorry if the question is too basic, but I am missing a lot of knowledge for this course

Answer (score 0):

We have $$A = \{a \leq x \leq b, 0 \leq y, 0 \leq f(x) - y\}.$$
View this as the intersection of three sets. The first set in the intersection is measurable because $(x, y) \mapsto x$ is measurable. The second set in the intersection is measurable because $(x, y) \mapsto y$ is measurable. The third set is measurable because $(x, y) \mapsto f(x) - y$ is measurable (here we only need $f$ to be measurable). The intersection of measurable sets is measurable, so $A$ is measurable.

Comment: I would proceed similarly, but argue that each of the three sets is closed, because each of the three maps mentoned is continuous, so $A$ s closed.  And only then conclude $A$ is measurable.  I'm guessing a beginner will more easily see why $(x, y) \mapsto f(x) - y$ is continuous than why it is measurable.